# Add values in database

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python, and I'm trying to make a program as part of a project. I'm trying to get the program to add a quote for a new customer in my code, however it keeps on giving the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/CompSci/CompSci Tradtional Exemplar/Python Traditional Program Actual.py", line 549, in <module>
    sys.exit()
SystemExit
```

This is the shell which is shown to me prior to the error:

```
1. Search for a quote
2. Add quote
3. Monthly report
4. Exit
2
1. Add quote for existing client
2. Add quote for new client
2
Add new client name:
name
could not save new client to database
No client was selected
```

This is part of the code:

```
import sys
import csv
import sqlite3
import datetime
import time

# constants used in the program
LABOURPERHOUR = 16.49
DB = 'gardening.db'
MATERIALFILE = 'materials.txt'

# structure of the database
def runFirstTime():
    # use try-except to catch any database errors
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(DB)
            c = conn.cursor()
            # create the client table with its two attributes
            # client is created first because clientID is a foreign key in the quote table
            query='''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client (clientID int, clientName text, primary key(clientIDc.execute(query)))'''
            conn.commit()
            # create the quote table with 24 attributes
            query = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS quote (
quoteID int,
clientID int,
dayOfQuote int,
monthOfQuote int,
yearOfQuote int,
dayOfJob int,
monthOfJob int,
yearOfJob int,
lawnLength real,
lawnWidth real,
lawnCostPerM real,
patioLength real,
patioWidth real,
patioCostPerM real, deckingLength real,
deckingWidth real, deckingCostPerM real,
pondLength real,
pondWidth real,
pondCostPerM real,
featureNumber int, featuresCostEa real, lightingNumber int, lightingCostEa real,
primary key (quoteID),
foreign key (clientID) references
client(clientID))'''
            c.execute(query)
            conn.commit()
            c.close()
        except:
            pass

# read in the costs from the external file
def getCostsFromFile(filename):
    # save the results in a dictionary
    costs = {}
    try:
        # use the built in CSV reader
        fileReader = csv.reader(open(MATERIALFILE, 'r'))
        # loop over the rows
        for row in fileReader:
            # the text becomes the key in the dictionary and the float is the value
            costs[row[0]] = float(row[1])
        return costs
    except:
        print ("make sure materials.txt exists and is in the correct format")
        sys.exit()

# procedure to display the four options
def displayMenu():
    print ("1. Search for a quote")
    print ("2. Add quote")
    print ("3. Monthly report")
    print ("4. Exit")

# procedure that calculates all of the costs for a quote and displays it
def displayQuote(quoteData):
    # runningTotals keeps the costs of the materials in a dictionary
    runningTotals = {}
    # keeps a running total
    totalMaterialCost = 0.0

# procedure if a new quote is added to the system
def newQuote():
    # choice is displayed
    print ("1. Add quote for existing client")
    print ("2. Add quote for new client")
    menuChoice = input()
    # input is validated (either 1 or 2)
    while menuChoice not in ['1', '2']:
        print ("Enter either 1 or 2")
        menuChoice = input()
    # the clientNumber is got by either method
    if menuChoice == '1':
        clientNumber = displayClients()
    else:
        clientNumber = addClient()
    # check to see if the user choose a client
    if not clientNumber:
        print ("No client was selected")
        return
    print ("Entering a quote for client " + str(clientNumber))
    # enter all the quote data into a dictionary
    quoteData = {}
    # each entry is validated either as float or an int
    # with the prompt to the user and the minimum value
    quoteData['lawnLength'] = getValidFloat("Enter lawn length", 0)
    quoteData['lawnWidth'] = getValidFloat("Enter lawn width", 0)
    quoteData['patioLength'] = getValidFloat("Enter patio length", 0)
    quoteData['patioWidth'] = getValidFloat("Enter patio width", 0)
    quoteData['deckingLength'] = getValidFloat("Enter decking length", 0)
    quoteData['deckingWidth'] = getValidFloat("Enter decking width", 0)
    quoteData['pondLength'] = getValidFloat("Enter pond length", 0)
    quoteData['pondWidth'] = getValidFloat("Enter pond width", 0)
    quoteData['featureNumber'] = getValidInt("Enter number of water features",0)
    quoteData['lightingNumber'] = getValidInt("Enter number of lighting features", 0)
    # this information is added to the database
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB)
        c = conn.cursor()
        # todays date is got using this built in function
        today = datetime.date.today()
        # the day, month and year is found out from the date
        quoteDay = today.day
        quoteMonth = today.month
        quoteYear = today.year
        # the primary key is a time in milliseconds (will be unique)
        quoteID = int(time.time())
        # this is a tuple of all the data to be added
        entries = (quoteID, clientNumber, quoteDay, quoteMonth, quoteYear,
quoteData['lawnLength'], quoteData['lawnWidth'], costs['lawnCostPerMetre'], quoteData['patioLength'], quoteData['patioWidth'], costs['patioCostPerMetre'], quoteData['deckingLength'], quoteData['deckingWidth'], costs['deckingCostPerMetre'],
quoteData['pondLength'], quoteData['pondWidth'], costs['pondCostPerMetre'],
quoteData['featureNumber'], costs['featureCost'], quoteData['lightingNumber'], costs['lightingCost'])
        # this is the query to insert all of the data
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO quote(quoteID, clientID, dayOfQuote, monthOfQuote, yearOfQuote, lawnLength, lawnWidth,
lawnCostPerM, patioLength, patioWidth, patioCostPerM, deckingLength, deckingWidth, deckingCostPerM, pondLength,
pondWidth, pondCostPerM, featureNumber, featureCostEa, lightingNumber, lightingCostEa) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', entries)
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
    except:
        # an error message in case the data couldn't be saved
        print ("quote could not be saved to database")
        print("Quote reference number:", quoteID)
        print(displayQuote(quoteData))
#    print "Quote reference number:",
#    print quoteID
#    displayQuote(quoteData)

# validates user input based on type (float) and a minimum value
def getValidFloat(prompt, minValue):enter code here
    valid = False
    answer = input(prompt)
    while not valid:
        try:
            # this will cause an error if it is the wrong type and
            # will be False if it is greater than the min value
            if float(answer) >= minValue:
                valid = True
        except:
            answer = input("Enter a valid number")
    # returns the answer in the correct type
    return float(answer)

# same as getValidFloat only for integer
def getValidInt(prompt, minValue):
    valid = False
    answer = input(prompt)
    while not valid:
        try:
            if int(answer) >= minValue:
                valid = True
        except:
            answer = input("Enter a valid number")
    return int(answer)


# function to add a new client, returns the clientID
def addClient():
    print ("Add new client name:")
    # get the client name from user input
    clientName = input()
    # check they have entered something
    while not clientName:
        clientName = input("Add a name")
        print(int(time.time()))
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(DB)
        c = conn.cursor()
        # get the current time in milliseconds to be the primary key (will be unique)
        clientNumber = int(time.time())
        # SQL to add a new client
        c.execute('''INSERT INTO client VALUES(?,?)''', (clientNumber, clientName))
        conn.commit()
        c.close()
        # return the primary key
        return clientNumber

    except:
        # error message if database error
        print ("could not save new client to database")
    return



## the 'main' part - where the program starts
if __name__ =='__main__':
    # check the database exists and if not create the tables
    runFirstTime()

    # get all the costs from the external file
    costs = getCostsFromFile(MATERIALFILE)

    # carry on going round (the user exits by choosing 4)
    while True:
        # display the main menu
        displayMenu()
        menuChoice = input()
        # validate the user input as being 1-4
        while menuChoice not in ['1','2','3','4']:
            displayMenu()
            menuChoice = input("Enter a number 1-4")
        # choose the correct procedure based on the user input
        if menuChoice == '1':
            searchQuote()
        elif menuChoice == '2':
            newQuote()
        elif menuChoice == '3':
            monthReport()
        else:
        # if they choose 4 then exit
            print ("system closing")
        sys.exit()
```

For now, I am just trying to get the new quote thing to work, then I will look at the other parts. This is what is in the `materials.txt` file:

```
lawnCostPerMetre,15.50
patioCostPerMetre,20.99
deckingCostPerMetre,15.75
pondCostPerMetre,25.00
featureCost,150.00
lightingCost,5.00
lawnMinutes,20.00
patioMinutes,20.00
deckingMinutes,30.00
pondMinutes,45.00
featureMinutes,60.00
lightingMinutes,10.00
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, note that it isn't an error, it's **exactly what you've asked the program to do**. If you don't want it to exit, **why call `sys.exit`?!**

Comment: I want the program to change the database and add a name instead of exit the shell.

Comment: This is what it says before the message:                                                    Add new client name:
name
could not save new client to database
No client was selected

Comment: Please see my previous comment. Just dumping your whole GCSE coursework is not a constructive way to ask a question. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/3001761

Comment: This is not my coursework, I'm testing out the one on the website to get a better understanding of it. It is the exemplar one: http://filestore.aqa.org.uk/subjects/AQA-GCSE-COMPSCI-W-TRB-S3LG.PDF

Comment: That really doesn't matter. The point remains: **shorten your code**. Nobody is going to trawl through all of that. One hint, though: http://blog.codekills.net/2011/09/29/the-evils-of--except--/

Comment: It looks like it likely just needs some [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather than tell you exactly what might be wrong; my suggestion if for you to get rid of the try except; or alternatively print the exception.

Using a try-except the way you have is not recommended as it's too vague and when you run into issues like this you have no idea what exception was caught.

When you figure out (for example through trial and error if you are a beginner) what exceptions are common then you can add back in the try except with specific exceptions (for example AttributeError, ValueError, whatever). But for now get rid of the try except so you can see what's causing the exception.

Comment: I'm referring to the try-except in the addClient() function by the way; something is causing an exception which you are catching with your catch-all-errors try-except; and so this line is being run: print ("could not save new client to database"); instead of the actual exception which would tell you what's happening. It's most likely a problem connecting to the database but I'd encourage you to figure it out for yourself (for the purposes of learning) by removing the try-except from the addClient() function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the addClient() function this is the error message you will get when it can't connect to the database. 
You typed name and addClient tried to connect to database name, which probably doesn't exist and it then gave the exception could not save new client to database. 
After that it returns and calls sys.exit. 
Looks like it's behaving like it should. 
Enter a valid database and test again.

Comment: Worse, that's the error message you get *whatever goes wrong*, which makes debugging pretty much impossible...

Comment: Indeed I'm only guessing now (based on the edited question and probable reasons)

Comment: You're right, I debugged it a while ago. The table called client wasn't created properly. So  have modified it now.